# DropDownListFor without a List type

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller, salesforce

I am currently working with the Salesforce API to basically pull data from Salesforce and push it back.

There is this one section where I need to pull the Data and Deserialize it so I have model access to it.

This certain property in the model, called Subject, is not of type list because there aren't multiple of them, BUT there are multiple Subjects from different objects coming in, and thats what I want to put in the dropdown.

How would I go about this?

My GetAllEvents() method in my Services.

```
        public async Task<SFEventModel> GetAllEvents()
        {
            HttpClient queryClient = new HttpClient();
            var tm = await GetToken();
            List<SelectListItem> events = new List<SelectListItem>();

            string restQuery = tm.ServiceUrl + "/services/data/v25.0/query?q=SELECT+Subject+from+Event";

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, restQuery);


            // Adding the token to the header 
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tm.AccessToken);
            // Return JSON to the caller
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //Call Endpoint Async
            HttpResponseMessage response = await queryClient.SendAsync(request);

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SFEventModel>(responseString);

            return model;
        }
```

My half-assed attempt of putting these inbound objects into a list

```
    <div class="text-center">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Subject)
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Subject, new SelectList(Model.Subject))
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am going to filter out all the other properties as they have no context to this question and there are lots of properties. I have the data pulling correctly from this model in my controller to actually pull "PicklistValues", but the problem is, it is considered a type.

```
public partial class Field 
{
[JsonProperty("picklistValues")
public PicklistValue[] PicklistValues { get; set; }
}
```

PicklistValue partial class in model -->

```
public partial class PicklistValue
        {
            [JsonProperty("active")]
            public bool Active { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("defaultValue")]
            public bool DefaultValue { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("label")]
            public string Label { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("validFor")]
            public object ValidFor { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
```

method in controller to pull these values coming in from the API call.

```
var allEvents = await _api.GetAllEvents();
var subjectList = allEvents.Fields.Where(x => x.Name == "Subject").Select(x => x.PicklistValues).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What subjects are there and where do you get them?

Comment: There are many, like "Call", "Email", "Text", blah blah and they are coming from Salesforce picklist values but I want to bring them into my website to basically make a dropdown with them

Comment: Could you post your model?

Comment: Updated post, should see it there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **SOLVED**

Might have just worded the question wrong but I did it.

My Index action in my HomeController had to have this method -> 

`ViewData["Picklist1"] = new SelectLit(await GetSubject(), "Value", "Label")`

and my view had to have this 

`<select asp-items="ViewBag.Picklist1"> </select>`

for the curious, my GetSubject method was tailored to the fact that Salesforce API is terrible.

```
private async Task<List<PicklistValue>> GetSubject()
 {
    var allEvents = await _api.GetAllEvents();
    var subjectList = allEvents.Fields.Where(x => x.Name == "Subject").Select(x => 
           x.PicklistValues).FirstOrDefault().ToList();

    return subjectList;
 }
```